# What about the opposite of stagflation

Tags: aggregate-supply

Mankiw says that a left shift in AS leads to higher inflation and unemployment and a higher expected inflation level, which shifts AS even more left and does this continuously. I was wondering though, if AS shifts right, wouldn't expected price level decrease and hence AS would shift even more right because more production is profitable? However, I didn't see this show up anywhere in the book or anything. Thanks